# Oracle SQL Function XMLISVALID returns allways 0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xml-db

knows someone why this statement delivers me the result 0 and not 1

```
SELECT XMLISVALID( XMLType('<Termin Nr="498">
                           <Beginn>10.06.03</Beginn>
                           <Ende>13.06.03</Ende>
                           <Kurs>1015068</Kurs>
                        </Termin>'),
                XMLType('<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
                <xs:element name="Termin">
                   <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                         <xs:element name="Beginn" type="xs:string"/>
                         <xs:element name="Ende" type="xs:string"/>
                         <xs:element name="Kurs" type="xs:int"/>
                       </xs:sequence>
                       <xs:attribute name="Nr" type="xs:short" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                 </xs:element></xs:schema>'))
FROM dual;
```

There are no more details possible

Comment: because xsd's should be registed in the database. check `DBMS_XMLSCHEMA`